# .net sockets ObjectDisposed exception

Tags: .net, sockets

I am using async sockets in my project.

When i calling Disconnect method in my class NotifyConnection ObjecDispoded exception arises.
I realize that that happen becaouse socket.Close() method calls Dispose inside.

Have anyone idea how close socket in this situation ?

```
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {                    
                _clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                _clientSocket.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            OnSocketExeceptionThrowed(new EventArgs<SocketException>(ex));
            NotificationAgentEm.LogExceptionToConsole(ex);
        }

    }
```

I expcect what EndReceive not called because socket.ShutDown closes socket receiving data..but EndReceive called after socket.ShutDown;socket.Close.

End exception throwed because socket not exist at this moment.

```
   private void OnReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            TransferStateObject state = null;
            lock(_syncRoot)
            {
                string message;
                state = (TransferStateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                // in this place exception throwed . client socket not exist becaouse it destroyed in disconnect method
                int bytesRead = _clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
```

keleton of how i using async sockets.

```
   public void Connect(string host, int port)
    {
        if (host == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();            
        try
        {
            _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                   SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _clientSocket.Connect(host, port);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            NotificationAgentEm.LogExceptionToConsole(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
   public void Disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {                    
                _clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                _clientSocket.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            OnSocketExeceptionThrowed(new EventArgs<SocketException>(ex));
            NotificationAgentEm.LogExceptionToConsole(ex);
        }

    }
       public void StartListen()
    {
        if (_clientSocket == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No connection");
        }
        try
        {
            BeginReceive();
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {              
            NotificationAgentEm.LogExceptionToConsole(ex);
            OnSocketExeceptionThrowed(new EventArgs<SocketException>(ex));
        }
    }  

  private void BeginReceive()
    {
        try
        {
            var receivedTranferObject = new TransferStateObject();
            _clientSocket.BeginReceive(
                receivedTranferObject.Buffer,
                0,
                TransferStateObject.BufferSize,
                0,
                new AsyncCallback(OnReceiveData),
                receivedTranferObject);
        }
        catch(SocketException ex)
        {
            OnSocketExeceptionThrowed(new EventArgs<SocketException>(ex));
            NotificationAgentEm.LogExceptionToConsole(ex);
        }
    }
  private void OnReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            TransferStateObject state = null;
            lock(_syncRoot)
            {
                string message;
                state = (TransferStateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                // in this place exception throwed . client socket not exist becaouse it    destroyed in disconnect method
                int bytesRead = _clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
                 //bla bla bla
             }
         }
```

p.s sorry for my english

Comment: You don't have to close the connection once its disposed as far as I know.

Comment: It is hard to tell where the problem is, you need to give us more details on the 'main loop'

Comment: If you think that Disconnect is called while still receiving data then check your program logic. You could also set a breakoint in Disconnect and see where the call is originating from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of my comment above I would restructure the Disconnect method:

```
try
{
  lock (_syncRoot)
  {                    
      if ( null != _clientSocket )
      {
           _clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
           _clientSocket.Close();
           _clientSocket = null;
       }
   }
}
catch (SocketException ex)
...
```

So you do not shutdown/ close the socket a second time around.

But again, to really help you we would need more details on the main workflow.

hth

PS: I do know about the penalty of having the if inside the lock, but I wanted to keep it simple,

Mario

EDIT: I added the function after the discussion in the comments section:

```
private void OnReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  if ( null != _clientSocket )
  { 
     try
      {
        TransferStateObject state = null;
        lock(_syncRoot)
        {
          string message;
          state = (TransferStateObject)ar.AsyncState;
          int bytesRead = _clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
          //bla bla bla
        }
      }
   }
  else
  {
    //socket has been closed/ is closing
   }
}
```

hth

Mario

Comment: i updated question.
locke inside the code i places to prevent disconnect at moment then socket receives and compute some information

Comment: restructure doesn't help( now null reference exception arises at EndReceive method

Comment: Does this problem only occurr when you are finishing the connection/ closing the application or also when you are receiveing data?

Comment: only when i finishing connection 'socket.ShutDown();socket.Disconnect()' not works too..despite the fact that on client socket.Connected = false hence connection closed..
after shutdown server "connection broken" exception throwed.

Comment: Have you tried adding a check in OnBeginRead? I added that to my post!